# "format" function when keywords may not exist

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to do this in Python:

```
print "Test {one} Hello {another} Third {something}".format(**args)
```

Where "args" is a dict.

Is there anyway that I can use this function while not throwing an Exception if one (or more) of the keywords (in the string above) doesn't exist in "args"?

I can't just catch the exception, because I want the rest of the string to print. A "blank" or anything is fine for non-existent keywords.

Anyone know of any clever ways of dealing with this in-general? I run into it a lot and typically build a separate dict which is "safe-checked" against missing (or in my case *optional* data).